# How to specify the types of multiple return values

Tags: go

Sometimes i find Go code hard to read when a function returns multiple values and their types are not specified. Is this possible ? See below:

```
func randomNumber()(int, error) {
    return 4, nil 
}

func main() {
    nr, err := randomNumber()
    // What i would like to do:
    // var nr int, err error = randomNumber()
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, that's not possible.  However, you could define the variables ahead of time to make it a little easier to follow.

```
func randomNumber()(int, error) {
    return 4, nil 
}

func main() {
    var nr int
    var err error
    // Note the '=' instead of ':='
    nr, err = randomNumber()
}
```